# Session value can't be updated, why?

Tags: php, session

I am using the following code on the server of a client:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['count']++;
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Here is the thing: when I refresh the page, it keeps displaying 1 as a value for $_SESSION['count']

What parameter should I look into in the phpinfo() to see where the problems come from?

I am kind of stuck here, any idea of what could be wrong? Thanks.

UPDATE: problem solved, the session.save_path parameter wasn't set correctly on the server.

Comment: your code works for me! check "Enable Caching" section on .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Are you initializing it anywhere?

```
$_SESSION['count'] = isset($_SESSION['count']) ? $_SESSION['count'] + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: It shouldn't return `0`, if it did, you aren't finishing the ternary operator. It should be 1.

Comment: UPDATE: problem solved, the session.save_path wasn't correctly set on the server. Thanks for your answers anyway.